# Generic method that can take both arrays and arraylists

Tags: java, sorting, generics

I am trying to write a generic mergesort method that will work for both arrays and arraylists, but I'm not sure whether this is possible, given that the two structures have different methods/syntax for adding/retrieving elements.

Comment: Overloading sounds like your jam.

Comment: Is it not possible to do it without overloading, because that kind of defeats the whole purpose of the genericity of the method.

Comment: @Tarlen It doesn't defeat the purpose whatsoever - on the contrary it's a neat way of achieving it.

Answer (score 3):

I would just write the method to take a list, and then write a second method that accepts an array, which delegates to the first method.  If you use Arrays.asList, any changes you make to the List should get written through to the original array.

```
public  <T> void mergeSort(T array []) {
    mergeSort(Arrays.asList(array));
}

public <T> void mergeSort(List<T> list) {
    // do sort here
}
```

Comment: But my assignment is to write a single method

Comment: There is no real world value to making it a single method.  In the code above, the CODE is not duplicated, which is the important part.

Answer (score 2):

You can't write one specific method that sorts both these exactly the same way, but you can write one method that overloads and delegates to the other:

```
public void mergeSort(List<Integer> list) {
    Integer[] arr = list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
    mergeSort(arr);
    list.clear();
    for(int num : arr) {
        list.add(num);
    }
}

public void mergeSort(Integer[] arr) {
    //Actual sorting logic
}
```

You can't do this with one method unless you tell it to accept `Object` and start throwing exceptions if it's the wrong type, which is obviously not goo practice at all!

Comment: @ZouZou Doh, sorry. Fixed.

Comment: I also don't think this will work, because changes to the array, will not get written through to the backing list.  When you call list.toArray, you get a shallow copy.

Comment: @mattforsythe Sorry, another brain freeze moment... fixed now.

Comment: If you do the delegation in the other direction, then you can use Arrays.asList() which will build a list backed by the actual array. Then you save yourself from having to do the work of copying the items back into the list.

Comment: But my assignment is to write a single method

Comment: @Tarlen As above, it's not possible without accepting object as a parameter, which is nasty stuff.